# Using SignalR for data update with AngularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, signalr

I'm quite confused about SignalR. My problem is simple but I'm not sure how to handle it.

I'm displaying some data into tables ( by calling web APIs using http.get the angular way ). Data itself is updated every X minutes ( cron job on server side ) and can be refreshed on button click ( client side ). The problem is that currently you need to refresh the whole page to update the displayed data. My goal is to create a server push at each data refresh ( server side ) and of course update the displayed data ( client side ) without having to refresh the page. I'm not totally sure about the implementation but I'll keep on digging some tutorials. Do you consider this to be a correct approach ?

I know it seems to be really easy, but it's my first attempt at using SignalR.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: How about using sql server dependency, this could give you an idea: http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/

Comment: I've used SignalR for a scenario very similar to what you are facing.  I had great success with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of how CRON jobs work, but if it is not a .Net, you can create simple API that can be called from the cron job, and inside this API, you will send a message from SignalR Hub which will notify all connected clients or some clients as per your needs.

This is a link that explains how to connect your browser through JavaScript to a SignalR hub
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

and this is how to send a message from .Net backend to a Hub, this will be used in the cron job

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr

Comment: I should have used the term "scheduled job" ( using Quartz.Net ). Your solution seems to be nice and easy, I'm going to give it a try !